# Error 1215 while creating foreign key on varchar column

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE  `rajesh_testing`.`testing1` (
  `EMPLOYEE_NAME` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `EMPLOYEE_SALARY` decimal(14,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EMPLOYEE_NAME`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE  `rajesh_testing`.`testing2` (
  `TEST2_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TEST2_EMPLOYEE_NAME` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TEST2_ID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (TEST2_EMPLOYEE_NAME) REFERENCES testing1(EMPLOYEE_NAME) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

while creating table testing2 am getting error 1215 cannot create foreign key.

Comment: I recommend this: `CREATE TABLE  testing1 
( EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar(25) NOT NULL, 
 EMPLOYEE_SALARY decimal(14,0) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_NAME) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
 ... 
CREATE TABLE  testing2 
( TEST2_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  
 TEST2_EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
 FOREIGN KEY (TEST2_EMPLOYEE_NAME) REFERENCES testing1(EMPLOYEE_NAME) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Comment: or slightly more simple: `CREATE TABLE  testing1 
( EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar(25) PRIMARY KEY, 
 EMPLOYEE_SALARY decimal(14,0) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
 ... 
CREATE TABLE  testing2 
( TEST2_ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
 TEST2_EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
 FOREIGN KEY (TEST2_EMPLOYEE_NAME) REFERENCES testing1(EMPLOYEE_NAME) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
`

Comment: Use the `engine=InnoDB` for FK's and cascades